# How to use $filter in OData query

Tags: linq, wcf-data-services, odata, windows-store-apps

I have a problem consuming an OData-service in a Windows 8 store application.

If I do this:

```
IEnumerable<vw_mobSurveyor> lstSurveyors =
    await ((DataServiceQuery<vw_mobSurveyor>)ODataContext.vw_mobSurveyor
        .AddQueryOption("$filter", "intSurveyorID eq " + intID.ToString()))
        .ExecuteAsync("GetByID").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

it works and the end of the URI is: `/vw_mobSurveyor?$filter=intSurveyorID eq 1`. This URI also works if I try it in a browser, so all is well.

But if I do :

```
IEnumerable<vw_mobSurveyor> lstSurveyors = 
    await ((DataServiceQuery<vw_mobSurveyor>)ODataContext.vw_mobSurveyor
        .Where(s => s.intSurveyorID == intID))
        .ExecuteAsync("GetByID").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This fails with a Client Internal Error 4.  It produces a different ending to the URI: `/vw_mobSurveyor(2)` This URI fails when I try it in a browser, and that is why it fails when the code generates it.

I have read these two should be equivalent in the produced URI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622463.aspx#filtering.

As I would like to pass a Linq expression in future, so I need to get the second version to work. So how do I force the second version to use `$filter` so it works?

Update : Fiddler output for working code using $filter

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 1057
Content-Type: application/atom+xml;type=feed;charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 18 Jan 2013 11:35:34 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="http://MYSERVER/TESTAPP%20V1/DataService.svc/"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <id>http://MYSERVER/TESTAPP%20V1/DataService.svc/vw_mobSurveyor</id>
  <title type="text">vw_mobSurveyor</title>
  <updated>2013-01-18T11:35:34Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="vw_mobSurveyor" href="vw_mobSurveyor" />
  <entry>
    <id>http://MYSERVER/TESTAPP%20V1/DataService.svc/vw_mobSurveyor(2)</id>
    <category term="SurveyProModel.vw_mobSurveyor" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <link rel="edit" title="vw_mobSurveyor" href="vw_mobSurveyor(2)" />
    <title />
    <updated>2013-01-18T11:35:34Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:intSurveyorID m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:intSurveyorID>
        <d:vchName>Bob Green 2</d:vchName>
        <d:vchStatus>Surveyor</d:vchStatus>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Update : Fiddler output for failing code

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 824
Content-Type: application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 18 Jan 2013 11:33:30 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xml:base="http://MYSERVER/TESTAPP%20V1/DataService.svc/"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <id>http://MYSERVER/TESTAPP%20V1/DataService.svc/vw_mobSurveyor(2)</id>
  <category term="SurveyProModel.vw_mobSurveyor" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
  <link rel="edit" title="vw_mobSurveyor" href="vw_mobSurveyor(2)" />
  <title />
  <updated>2013-01-18T11:33:30Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:intSurveyorID m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:intSurveyorID>
      <d:vchName>Bob Green 2</d:vchName>
      <d:vchStatus>Surveyor</d:vchStatus>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

Comment: In what way does it fail in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a bug in the WCF Data Services client.

At first glance, I don't see any issues in the Fiddler traces you provided, but I'll try to reproduce this on my end and I'll file an internal bug for this. If you have a **full stack trace** of the error, that would be very helpful.

Just to note: the LINQ-to-URI translation bit is doing the correct thing here. If a `.Where` clause is only checking the key value of an entity, we optimize the query by directly looking up the entity by its key (i.e., ../vw_mobSurveyor(2)) instead of using the `$filter` mechanism. This will result in an entry response payload instead of a feed, which matches what you got from Fiddler.

And to answer your original question, you could force the LINQ translator to use `$filter` by making the predicate involve anything other than the just the entity key. For example, you could do something like:

```
.Where(s => s.intSurveyorID == intID && true)
```

This is obviously a hack, but it should work. Ideally, we'll find and fix this bug and you can then use a more normal-looking Where clause :).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are querying a view; have you set the entity key property in your entity model?

Comment: Yes it is a view, and it has got the entity key set to true for intSurveyorID.  I will give it a try on a table instead of a view.

Comment: I have tried this on a table now, that also has the entity key set, and this does the same thing.

Comment: What does Fiddler log when you access the ../vw_mobSurveyor(2) uri in the browser?

Comment: I have updated the question to show the fiddler XML for both working and non-working.  Note : I have edited my IP address in both of these.

Comment: The fiddler output for the failing code suggests success; strange that it throws an error in the browser. Only real difference i can see between the two is that one returns a feed whereas the other returns just an entry but, the client should still be able to materialise that into an IEnumerable.